# PHP Rand duplicating on mysql insert

Tags: php

im trying to insert records in my table and have a unique id for each.

To do this i'm using the rand() function...

```
<input type="hidden" name="randkey" value="<?php echo rand(0000000000,9999999999);?>" />
```

My only problem is on each insert my random key/value seems to be the same? Surely on each page refresh this value should change? Can anybody explain why this may be happening?

Comment: Let your database generate the unique random number, it can do that better than you.

Comment: Why not use AUTO_INCREMENT for an id?

Comment: Is it possible that the page is being cached?

Comment: If you are using a templating system, or if you hit the back button, it is veri likely to happen what @EricPetroelje mentioned. Most of the templating systems can cache something like this. It is impossible statistically speaking to hit the same random number between multiple requests. Also please look at [mt_rand](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) for "better" random number generation.

Answer (score 8):

> im trying to insert records in my table and have a unique id for each.

Well, you have to set up this id as `PRIMARY KEY auto_increment` and obviously refrain from such silly ways as your current one.

Comment: Ahh, refreshing common sense :)

Comment: To add to this, unless you have some specific cases where an incrementing integer ID is not good for you, you should be using an auto_increment as your primary key.  that is what this functionality was specifically made for... to generate a unique id for each record. this is not to mention that if you wanted to use a random id in your current manner, why would you expose it as an input field which can easily be changed by the end user, rather then do this in your server-side code?